# How to correctly order NSArray of NSDates respecting Year, Month then Day order?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsarray

I have this method that returns an NSArray of dates. The problem is that, when displaying the graph the order of dates is not correct when the dates have different years.

For example, if have these dates: 12/25/13, 01/18/14, 12/28/13, 02/22/14; the method will return like this: 01/18/14, 02/22/14, 12/25/13, 12/28/13.

I need the dates ordered respecting the Year order first, then month, then day. So the final array should be like this:  12/25/13, 12/28/13, 01/18/14, 02/22/14.

So anyone can point what's wrong with the code?

```
- (NSArray *)graphViewSortedMonths:(SimpleStockView *)graphView {


NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSArray *closingDates = [[DailyTradeInfoSource dailyTradeInfos] valueForKeyPath:@"tradingDate"];
//NSLog(@"%@", closingDates);

__weak NSCountedSet *months = [NSCountedSet set];
[closingDates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id closingDate, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    [months addObject:[calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:closingDate]];
}];
//NSLog(@"%@", months);

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"month" ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
NSLog(@"Months %@", [months sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]);

return [months sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

}
```

This is what I get when I NSLog:

```
014-03-24 04:10:48.697 SimpleStocks[6343:60b] Months (
"<NSDateComponents: 0x8c34af0>\n    Month: 1\n    Leap month: no",
"<NSDateComponents: 0x8c34c50>\n    Month: 2\n    Leap month: no",
"<NSDateComponents: 0x8c34cb0>\n    Month: 3\n    Leap month: no",
"<NSDateComponents: 0x8c349d0>\n    Month: 12\n    Leap month: no"
)
```

And it should be:

```
014-03-24 04:10:48.697 SimpleStocks[6343:60b] Months (
"<NSDateComponents: 0x8c349d0>\n    Month: 12\n    Leap month: no"
"<NSDateComponents: 0x8c34af0>\n    Month: 1\n    Leap month: no",
"<NSDateComponents: 0x8c34c50>\n    Month: 2\n    Leap month: no",
"<NSDateComponents: 0x8c34cb0>\n    Month: 3\n    Leap month: no",
)
```

This is what I was getting:

[image: Wrong code]

This is the after the corrected code:

[image: Corrected Code]

Comment: If you have an array of dates, sorting it using compare: will give you the right answer. It sounds more like these are strings. And why is that set declared as weak? That will probably fail in a release build since under ARC it should set to nil straight away.

Comment: @jrturton I get the ordered array but when it draws on the graph the order is wrong as I pointed on the post. I edited my post for a better understanding of what  I am getting and what I need.

Comment: So, you're using the set because you want to group everything? I.e. You have an array of dates and you only want unique month / year combinations, or year / month / day combinations?

Comment: I want them in an NSArray ordered by Year and month Year combination.

Comment: It seems that you buys are not understanding what the problem is. the code sorts fine the dates. The problem is when it is going to be displayed on the graph, and you can see the NSLog results from months NSCountedSet. It displays the order by month, ok, but not respecting the year.

Comment: You're not explaining it. An array of dates sorted by year / month / day is _the same_ as an array of dates sorted in _date order_, so why aren't you just doing that?

Comment: I updated my question with what I am getting wrong on the graph. December should be displayed before February. The line graph is correct but the month names order is not.

Comment: There's no correlation between the example dates and the log output, right? How shall we understand what's going on and what you want?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I edited reorganized the pics so that You can understand what's going on and what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're extracting only the month DateComponents from your array of dates. If you just sort the months, they'll be in the order you're seeing: 1, 2, 3, 12.

I think instead, you want to extract both the months and years, and sort on year first, then month:

```
- (NSArray *)graphViewSortedMonths:(SimpleStockView *)graphView 
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSArray *closingDates = [[DailyTradeInfoSource dailyTradeInfos] valueForKeyPath:@"tradingDate"];

    NSCountedSet *monthsAndYears = [NSCountedSet set];
    [closingDates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id closingDate, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        [monthsAndYears addObject:[calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:closingDate]];
    }];

    NSSortDescriptor *monthDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"month" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *yearDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"year" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *descriptors = @[ yearDescriptor, monthDescriptor ];

    NSArray *result = [monthsAndYears sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
    NSLog(@"Months %@", [result valueForKeyPath:@"month"]);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Finally I got it working. I posted the pic with the correct displaying of months!!!

Answer (score -1):

if you are having array of date objects then you can use like below.

```
   - (NSMutableArray *)graphViewSortedMonths:(SimpleStockView *)graphView {
        NSMutableArray *dateObjects =  [NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    NSArray *closingDates = [[DailyTradeInfoSource dailyTradeInfos] valueForKeyPath:@"tradingDate"];

    [closingDates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id closingDate, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        [dateObjects addObject:closingDate];
    }];
    NSLog(@"LOG:%@", dateObjects);
    [dateObjects sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
       {
                return ([obj1 compare:obj2] == NSOrderedAscending);
        }];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSMutableArray *months =  [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSDate *obj in dateObjects){
        [months addObject:[calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:obj]];
    }
            return months;
        }
```

Comment: I got this error: 2014-03-24 04:25:08.584 SimpleStocks[6394:60b] -[__NSDate era]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c9e660

Comment: It seems that you buys are not understanding what the problem is. the code sorts fine the dates. The problem is when it is going to be displayed on the graph, and you can see the NSLog results from months NSCountedSet. It displays the order by month, ok, but not respecting the year.

Comment: check now..dateObjects should contain date objects

Comment: The methods returns fine an ordered, just like the method I used does. But still I get the same error I mentioned before: 2014-03-24 05:22:28.774 SimpleStocks[6728:60b] -[__NSDate era]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8efad50

Comment: the slog is too long to be displayed here, but I'll post a part of it.

Comment: 2014-03-24 05:31:34.770 SimpleStocks[6864:60b] dateObjects: (
    "2014-03-13 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2014-03-12 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2014-03-11 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2014-03-10 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2014-02-27 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2014-02-26 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2013-12-30 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2013-12-27 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2013-12-26 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2013-12-23 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2013-12-20 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2013-12-19 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2013-12-18 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2013-12-17 03:00:00 +0000",
    "2013-12-16 03:00:00 +0000"
)

Comment: As i understand [__NSDate era]: issue. previously my method returns date objects in array. But you are using as nsdateformater. Now i Had changed code. plz check.

Comment: The method returns and NSMutableArray and months is a NSCountedSet, so, code does not work.

Comment: I corrected the code, but didn't work, it just reordered to December, March, February, January.. I need, December (of 2013), January, February and March (all three of 2014).

Comment: Wow, last edit of yours gave me a bunch of March a one February.. Just like the second pic I posted now.